Comparison of HTTP response and JDBC response for any request in JMeter
I have API request for which I am getting the response in JSON & for the same data I need to verify /compare it with database as well .
Http request response :-
[
{
"name": "TRANSLATOR_MERGE_SIMILAR_STUDIES_ENABLED",
"value": "false"
}
]
JDBC response
PARAM_VALUE
false
NOw I want to assert the "False" from both the responses & make the case passed/failed.
Can anyone suggest something. I have 100 + similar requests for which I have to compare the data with DB vaules.


Extract value from HTTP response using JSON Extractor configured like this:


Extract value from the database using JDBC PostProcessor like this:


Compare the values using Response Assertion like this:


Enjoy



Thanks a ton Ivan G , it worked, can you please help me when the multiple values needs to be asserted from the same call
like :- if I want to compare both the values of the keys, then how to assert [ { "name": "TRANSLATOR_MERGE_SIMILAR_STUDIES_ENABLED", "value": "false" } ]
